# Correct usage of implementation / hidden namespace

Tags: c++11

Suppose in header file, we have something like this.

```
namespace impl_{
   int do_something_(){
      return 1;
   }
}

int do_something(){
   using namespace impl_;
   return do_something_();
}
```

`impl_::do_something_()` is well hidden, but it is "included" in the output object file.

If we want the function not to be included, we need to do it `inline` or `static`... or to add one more namespace???

```
namespace impl_{
namespace {
   int do_something_(){
      return 1;
   }
}
}
```

... actually, this works too...

```
namespace {
namespace impl_{
   int do_something_(){
      return 1;
   }
}
}
```

Note this imply to both header and implementation files, but for header files is bigger problem.

I am very confuse - what would be the best way / best practice to do this kind of "hiding implementation code" inside the header files?

Comment: Lots of choices. I think your last one: impl inside local. You don't really need the underscore appended in the function name if you have that impl to distinguish the local and global methods with the same name?
Note that your local namespace is still not totally secret. It usually still gets published in the object file as namespace <random-number>, so your method is still visible and in theory linkable to as <random>::impl::do_domething

Comment: Are you asking about hiding symbols in the generated (ELF?) binary? Does the code in your question belong to header or implementation files?

Comment: @jotik nice question, but I will edit, because it is much more related to header files.

Comment: @GemTaylor - why impl in local why not the opposite?

Comment: My feeling is you don't want one program-wide impl which is apparently empty, except the local namespaces, better to have the impl secret as well.

Comment: I hadn't really noticed your implementation here was in a header file.
That means that client code could still get to it by calling impl::method directly, as they are in the same local context.
It really depends what you are trying to hide and who from.

The classic model for this is at the class method level: pimpl.